# Elastic Search on Windows could not find or load main class

Tags: windows, powershell, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, kibana-7

I have installed Elastic Search version 7.15.1 in windows 10 using .msi package installer and when I am trying to run ES, it throws an error

**Error: Could not find or load main class Warning:**

I have also installed the latest version of Java

I am struck without any hunch on how to go ahead.

P.S i am a beginner

Comment: it'd be useful if you could share the Elasticsearch log

Comment: Hey @MarkWalkom, Please find the logs in the attached link

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PKxmFxi2kBNLEW7_JmBFpxAI6wQHPYHs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm happy to look at them, but please use gist/pastebin/etc

Comment: @MarkWalkom, I am sorry. I do not understand what is gist/pastebin/etc. Can you please explain

Comment: please put the logs into https://gist.github.com/ or https://pastebin.com/ or something else. not google drive

Comment: Hey Mark, apologies for the delay, 
https://pastebin.com/NKUSPyCX